# "Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain" - What domain?

Tags: feature-request, support

I've somewhat recently started seeing a red banner on top of every page, stating:

```
[Foo] Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load. Retry using another source.
```

Following the "Retry using another source" link fixes it, but only temporarily.

- Exactly what domain does it attempt to load, such that failing to do so results in this message?
- What does the "Retry using another source" link do?
  The uri suggests it involves jquery and cookies, but it immediately redirects to the main site when I hit the link. Assuming it is setting a cookie, what cookie does it set?

I'm sure that given enough time, I could reverse engineer the various scripts on the page and figure out what exactly it's complaining about, but might it be possible to instead include that information in the error message?

Comment: Maybe cookielaw.org

Comment: Used to be sstatic.net, not sure now.

Comment: @Draft85 I've got ajax.googleapis.com whitelisted, so probably not.

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog I'm not seeing anything to suggest that any of those domains are trying to load something and being blocked.

Comment: Just a stray thought, but you're not on Firefox 87.0 64 bit on windows 10. I've had trouble with that recently.

Comment: @Draft85 Firefox 87.0 64 bit on Linux.

Comment: I've no evidence only testimony of degradation in use. Covid related S/ware failure seems to turn-up in forums.

Comment: @Draft85 Firefox has been cracking down lately on Javascript that lets advertisers identify users, and I wouldn't be surprised if that has broken some sites. I'm inclined to think that Firefox is quite right to do this, and hope that this will encourage people to figure out how to write websites that *don't* require me to allow 20 third party sites to execute arbitrary code on my system for no good reason. </rant> But in the meantime, stackexchange is useful enough that I'd be willing to add the domains it depends on to my whitelists, if only I knew what they were.

Comment: It's clear you know at least a little bit about browsers, webpages, and networking, so I find it a bit frustrating that you ask a question which you should be ware that we **can't** answer with the information which you've provided. Frankly, the only person that can answer this is **you**, or someone with access to your machine, by using the developer tools available in your browser (e.g. the dev-tools networking tab, console, or other way of looking at what *your* browser and configuration blocked). You clearly know that what is blocked can vary by user/config, so why are you asking us?

Comment: @Makyen Because my question isn't "What setting should I change locally?". My question is "Some code on this site is attempting to load code from some domain. When it fails to do so, it *prints this specific error message*. What causes that to happen?" The question is about the stackexchange code, not my browser settings, and I'm hoping that someone who has access to that code (and can grep for that error message) reads meta. (After that question is answered, yes, I'll need to do some stuff locally, but I can probably handle that part myself, so I didn't ask about that step.)

Comment: @Ray As written, the question is *explicitly* asking which domain is being blocked *for you*. That's something *only you*, someone with access to your machine, or someone able to run code on your machine can determine. The error message you've described *is* generated by Stack Exchange's code, but the best we can do is give you a list of domains which *might* be blocked. We can't tell you exactly which domain *is* blocked. Someone with access to your machine will have to be the one to determine which domain *is* blocked.

Comment: OTOH, I can tell you which domain being blocked *on my machine* would produce that error message. On my machine, that would only be generated if the domain ajax.googleapis.com was blocked, or if all JavaScript was disabled in the browser. Looking in Stack Exchange's code, that error is generated if and only if loading of the page is complete and `window.jQuery` evaluates to a falsey value. In the code SE serves me, jQuery is loaded from "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js", which would need to fail. However, I can't say that domain *is* blocked for you.