# Automatically retry loading external JavaScript from another domain

Tags: feature-request, javascript

Every time I'm opening any Stack Exchange sites in a new web session (I'm doing it every day or sometimes multiple times per day), it shows me a banner " requires external JavaScript from another domain, which is blocked or failed to load. Retry using another source." with link for reloading https://meta.stackexchange.com/home/get-jquery-fallback-cookie

Each time I need to click this link to load from fallback URI. If I don't click, the side won't work correctly as described in similar questions about this banner:

- ["Stack Exchange requires external JavaScript from another domain" - What domain?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/363133/197674)
- [Can we have a list of all the Stack Exchange domains somewhere, for firewall purposes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/81379/197674)
- ["requires external JavaScript from another domain" error with googleapis ENABLED](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/90460/197674)

I'm proposing to do this automatically (programmatically on front-end): detect that some JavaScript code was not loaded correctly and try loading it from fallback URIs. It seems to be quite simple technically.

I don't see same problems on another websites with jQuery. I'm experiencing this issue only on Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: Similar recent report: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/370534/282094

Comment: Thanks, @RobertLongson this https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/133810/197674 can solve my problem. But it was suggested about 10 years ago, so most probably will never be implemented :)